# How to keep list of modules in database in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I don't want to keep it in config file

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ZfcUser',
        'ZfcBase',
        ...
    ),        
);
```

How can I load list of modules from database to zf2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best approach on this would be  : Write a module called YourModuleManager and let it do the management of modules with a few controllers 
then do what sam said in previous answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't. If you need to administrate the Module from an Administration-Panel i think the best approach would be to move the Modules-Array into it's own file like:

**application.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => require_once __DIR__ . 'application.modules.php',
    // rest of application.config.php
)
```

**application.modules.php**

```
<?php
return array(
    'Application',
    'ZfcBase',
    'ZfcUser',
    // more...
);
```

You can then use this file and write an administration front end to it. The file would be writeable obviously. Remember, that at the time of Module initialization, the Framework doesn't know about the database yet.

Answer (score 0):

Example: find by user id, when auth/login/etc. on Doctrine

```
$moduleRepository = $em->getRepository("your module\Entity\your class, where get all name module etc.");
$module = $moduleRepository->findOneByUser($user->getId());
$moduleName = $module->getName();
global $modules;
$modules[] = $moduleName;
```

// ...
// and add reload function...